# Transplanting into one changeset

Tags: mercurial, changeset, transplant

I'm trying to move changes from a couple of changesets into one changeset on the other branch. There are other changes in between that I want to skip, so I don't want to simply merge everything.

`hg transplant` moves the changes correctly, but now I'd like to flatten them into a single commit. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fold them by

1. Backup the repository, a **failure during the process can destroy data**
2. transplant the desired changes to the target branch
3. transform them there into a mercurial queue (`hg qimport -r first-to-fold-rev:`)
4. fold them into one patch (`hg qpop` until the first patch is applied, then `hg qfold <<patch name>>` the following patches into this one)
5. Edit the commit message (When there are **NO OUTSTANDING CHANGES** `hg qrefresh -e`)
6. apply the single patch to your repository (`hg qfinish -a`).
7. When there are further unfolded patches:

   1. `hg qpush` until the head patch
   2. `hg qfinish -a`
   3. Review the new repo state (`hg glog`/`hg incoming`)

Answer (score 1):

[`hg rebase`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseProject) has an '--collapse` option. I think this is what you are looking for.